# How do I get my USB keyboard to not freeze up in the recovery menu?

Tags: grub2, freeze, menu, data-recovery

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, and whenever I enter the recovery menu, my keyboard freezes and I can't make any selections. I have tried using `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="usb usb_keyboard"` but this doesn't help at all.
The keyboard works in the BIOS screen and in Grub (i can select an OS, write to the command line, etc.) but as soon as i get to the recovery menu it stops working. If i had the numlock on it will stay lit and i cannot turn it off, if that helps

Comment: I have the same problem with my Apple USB keyboard. There is a bug report in Launchpad about this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/friendly-recovery/+bug/203385

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and finally got it resolved. 
I had to unplug all my usb devices besides the keyboard (maybe there was just one that caused the issue, but I didn't want to try all possibilities). I also had to add 'acpi=off nohz=off' to my boot line in grub (hit 'e' in grub while the recovery mode is selected to change the boot line).

Comment: I tried only the code and it didn't fix it for me (I didn't try removing all of my other USB cords - maybe that would have solved it)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today, and with Johannes' answer was able to solve it - unplugging all USB devices except the keyboard worked.

Note though - when I first tried adding the suggested 'acpi=off nohz=off' to the boot line in grub, the keyboard was still non-responsive in recovery mode.

Trying again but NOT adding 'acpi=off nohz=off' *did* work.

Also, tried various combinations of USB devices (mouse, keyboard, external USB HD, ext USB hub on monitor), and the only combination that worked was "keyboard only".

Also tried adding/removing devices when the Recovery Menu was 'frozen' and it displayed alerts that devices were added or removed (always device 2 though).