# Messed install up with dpkg --configure -a

Tags: dpkg

I don't know how I did it but earlier today I was getting an error since I accidentally did a reboot during a routine software update. I looked online and the recommendation was to do a dpkg --configure -a to resolve the issue. I ran this command, and did another reboot, and now I can't even use my system. I am presented with the login screen at a low resolution, keyboard and mouse do not work. I attempted to use recovery mode, but the second it gives me the options to enable screen the keyboard stops working. Keyboard works fine on this old 13.10 live CD, as well as in Windows XP on the other partition. I attempted to add the options as listed here ([How do I get my USB keyboard to not freeze up in the recovery menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75358/how-do-i-get-my-usb-keyboard-to-not-freeze-up-in-the-recovery-menu)) but am not having any success.

Any ideas before I do a clean drive wipe? I may try to re-install 14.04 over 14.04 once I get the ISO downloaded as a option, but if not going to have to do a clean install.

// EDIT - Actually got this resolved by using the 13.10 "Live" CD, chrooting, doing sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get distupgrade

Comment: How to "chroot" -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Answer (score 0):

Run the following and see:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all
```

If this doesnt successfull, then run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all
```